# Position Fixed and overflow: auto don't show all content, also IE FIX?

Tags: html, css

My HTML and CSS Code:

```css
    rightframeLogin .username {
     width: 190px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 15px; color: #FFF;
     
     background: #2c4764;
    
    border-bottom: 2px solid #233950;
    }
    
    #rightframeLogin .password {
     width: 190px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 15px; color: #FFF;
     
     background: #2c4764;
    
    border-bottom: 2px solid #233950;
    }
    
    #rightframeLogin .submit {
     width: 190px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 5px;  color: #FFF;
     
     background: #2c4764;
    
    border-bottom: 2px solid #233950;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #rightframeLogin .submit:hover {
     background-color: #22374E;
     transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     
    }
    
    #rightframeLogin {
       -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
       -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
       box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
       height: 119px;
       font-weight: bold;
       
       position: fixed;
       right: 0;
       
       z-index: 3;
    }
    
        #rightframe {
         float: right;
         color: #FFF;
         width: 250px;
         /* box-sizing: border-box;
         padding: 5px; */
         color: #ff8a00;
         min-height: calc(100vh - 35px);
         margin-top: 35px;
          -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
           -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
           box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
           
           position: fixed;
           right: 0;
           z-index: -1;
        
        }
        
        
        #rightframe .left {
         background-color: #2c4764;
         width: 60px;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         padding: 5px;
         float: left;
         min-height: calc(100vh - 35px);
         height: 100%;
         color: #16304c;
        }
        
        #rightframe .right {
        
          float: righT;
          width: 190px;
          color: #000;
          min-height: calc(100vh - 154px);
          height: 100%;
          color: #FFF;
          
          -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
           -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
           box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
           
        }
        
        #rightframe .display {
           background-color: #243a51;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          padding: 5px;
          padding-top: 10px;
          /* padding-top: 20px; */
          
          /* FIXED  asd */
          
          
          position: fixed;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          top: 155px;
          overflow: auto;
          z-index: 5;
          height: 100%;
          
        }
```

```html
    <div id="rightframe">
    
     <div class="left">
      
      <div style="width: 40px; margin: auto;">
        <a id='south-east' href='#' title='This is an example of east gravity'><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x" id="fafa"></i></a>
       <a id='south-east1' href='hehe' title='Arkiv'><i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-3x" id="fafa"></i></a>
      
     
      
      </div>
      
     </div>
     
     <div class="right">
    
      
      <div id="rightframeLogin">
      
      <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Användarnamn" class="username"><br>
      <input type="password" name="passwd" class="password" placeholder="Lösenord"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Logga in" class="submit">
      </form>
      
      </div>
      
      
      <div class="right display">
      
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       
       inget dudå?
       
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
       
       inget dudå? vaaaaaaad 234234
       
       
       
      </div>
      
     </div>
    
    </div>
```

The box is named #rightframe .display , that is not working correctly. It don't show allt the content in the div bar. Why? Also is there a fix for IE?

If link is needed to understand the code tell me so I can link the webpage!

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. What is the issue? Yes, a link or demo would be useful.

Comment: http://royals.se.preview.citynetwork.se/line/index.php , Its the box at the right under the login box

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are setting the `.right.display`'s height to 100%. This is done in two places: once in the CSS rule for `.right` and once in the rule for `.display`.

I removed the `.right` class from the div.

I removed the `height:100%;` line from the `.display`'s rule.

Lastly, I added a `width:190px;` to the `.display` rule. (This was lost by removing the `.right` class from the element.)

You also have a bit of redundant css that could be cleaned up.

```css
rightframeLogin .username {
    width: 190px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 15px; color: #FFF;

    background: #2c4764;

border-bottom: 2px solid #233950;
}

#rightframeLogin .password {
    width: 190px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;   padding: 15px; color: #FFF;

    background: #2c4764;

border-bottom: 2px solid #233950;
}

#rightframeLogin .submit {
    width: 190px; border: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 5px;  color: #FFF;

    background: #2c4764;

border-bottom: 2px solid #233950;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#rightframeLogin .submit:hover {
    background-color: #22374E;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

}

#rightframeLogin {
         -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   height: 119px;
   font-weight: bold;

   position: fixed;
   right: 0;

   z-index: 3;
}

    #rightframe {
        float: right;
        color: #FFF;
        width: 250px;
        /* box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 5px; */
        color: #ff8a00;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 35px);
        margin-top: 35px;
         -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
       -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
       box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

       position: fixed;
       right: 0;
       z-index: -1;

    }


    #rightframe .left {
        background-color: #2c4764;
        width: 60px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
        min-height: calc(100vh - 35px);
        height: 100%;
        color: #16304c;
    }

    #rightframe .right {

            float: righT;
            width: 190px;
            color: #000;
            min-height: calc(100vh - 154px);
            height: 100%;
            color: #FFF;

         -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
       -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
       box-shadow: 2px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

    }

    #rightframe .display {
                background-color: #243a51;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 5px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            /* padding-top: 20px; */

            /* FIXED  asd */


            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            top: 155px;
            overflow: auto;
            z-index: 5;
      width:190px;

    }
```

```html
<div id="rightframe">

    <div class="left">

        <div style="width: 40px; margin: auto;">
          <a id='south-east' href='#' title='This is an example of east gravity'><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x" id="fafa"></i></a>
         <a id='south-east1' href='hehe' title='Arkiv'><i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-3x" id="fafa"></i></a>



        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="right">


        <div id="rightframeLogin">

        <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Användarnamn" class="username"><br>
        <input type="password" name="passwd" class="password" placeholder="Lösenord"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Logga in" class="submit">
        </form>

        </div>


        <div class="display">

            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>

            inget dudå?

            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>
            too vad gör du? haha hehe :D <br> <br>

            inget dudå? vaaaaaaad 234234



        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I did as you said but It didn't work, link: http://royals.se.preview.citynetwork.se/line/index.php

Comment: @user3502178 In your live site your removed the `.right` class from the wrong div. Look at the code snippet for reference.